# Create Maven app in Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, web-applications, netbeans

I want create Maven application in Netbeans. I use File-New Project-Maven-Web Applicatoion. The project was created. But project contains folder `Web Pages` only. In some tutorials is created folders Source Packages, Dependencies, Java Dependencies, Project Files too. Because is created only one folder Web Pages in my Netbeans?Thx

Comment: Manually create other.

Comment: I believe it depends on what javaee version is the newly created webapp.

Comment: Look at the output console. See if it was successful

Comment: mkleint: I tried this on JavaEE 5 and JavaEE 6 Web but in both cases is generated only one Web Pages folder.

Comment: peeskillet: In output is all right.